# miniz C can't zip file with absolute path

Tags: c, windows, filepath, miniz

I'm using miniz to create a .zip file in C, on Windows.

I used the doc to produce my code and it works. I can create an archive with the files I want, ONLY if I give relative path to the zip function.

I don't get why the "file_name" variable must be something like "../test/file.txt" and not "C:/../test/file.txt".

```
if (!(status = mz_zip_add_mem_to_archive_file_in_place(archive, file_name, data, strlen(data) + 1, s_pComment,
                                                           (uint16) strlen(s_pComment), MZ_BEST_COMPRESSION)))
        return (merror("add file to archive failed !!"));
```

Before this function, I open my file, get the data inside and call the zip_function with it.

```
    if (!(src = fopen(file_name, "r")))
        return (merror("can't open this file"));
    char *line = NULL;
    char *data= NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    getline(&line, &n, src);
    data= strdup(line);
    while (getline(&line, &n, src) != -1){
        data = realloc(save, sizeof(char) * (strlen(data) + strlen(line)) + 1);
        data = strcat(data, line);
    }
    fopen(src);
```

So I call the zip function with the archive name, the file name (with the absolute path) and the datas inside it (in char * format).

This is the "full" code : the function init_zip is the first function called by my program. The `arg` parameter is the archive name I want to be create(it can be an absolute path and works) and the `args` parameter are the names of the differents files I want to add to the archive file (relative path works but not absolute).

```
typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef unsigned int uint;

static const char *s_pComment = "";

static int isDirectory(const char *path) {
    struct stat statbuf;
    if (stat(path, &statbuf) != 0)
        return 0;
    return S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode);
}

int get_data(const char *archive, const char *file)
{
    FILE               *src;

    if (!isDirectory(file)) {
        if (!(src = fopen(file, "r")))
            return (merror("can't open this file"));
        char *line = NULL;
        char *save = NULL;
        size_t n = 0;
        getline(&line, &n, src);
        save = strdup(line);
        while (getline(&line, &n, src) != -1) {
            save = realloc(save, sizeof(char) * (strlen(save) + strlen(line)) + 1);
            save = strcat(save, line);
        }
        printf("compressing %s ..\n", file);
        if (m_compress(archive, file, save))
            return (merror("compress function failed"));
        printf(("\tOK.\n"));
        fclose(src);
    }
    else
    {
        DIR                *dir;
        struct dirent      *entry;
        char                *new_file;

        if (!(dir = opendir(file)))
            return (merror("opendir failed: ", "wrong directory path in init_zip.get_data command : ", file, NULL));
        while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..")) {
                new_file = add_path(file, entry->d_name);
                get_data(archive, new_file);
            }
        }
        if (new_file)
            free(new_file);
        closedir(dir);
    }
}

int init_zip(const char *arg, const char **args)
{
    printf("\nZIP cmd:\n >");
    remove(arg);
    for (int counter = 0; args[counter]; ++counter)
    {
       get_data(arg, args[counter]);
    }
    printf("All the files are added to %s archive file.\n", arg);
    return (0);
}

int m_compress(const char *archive, const char *file_name, const char *data)
{
    mz_bool status;

    if (data)
        if (!(status = mz_zip_add_mem_to_archive_file_in_place(archive, file_name, data, strlen(data) + 1, s_pComment,
                                                               (uint16) strlen(s_pComment), MZ_BEST_COMPRESSION)))
            return (merror("add file to archive failed !!"));
    else
        if (!(status = mz_zip_add_mem_to_archive_file_in_place(archive, file_name, NULL, 0, "no comment", (uint16)strlen("no comment"), MZ_BEST_COMPRESSION)))
            return (merror("add directory to archive failed !!"));

    return (0);
}
```

This is the `add_path()` function used in `get_data()`:

```
char          *add_path(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
  char *path;

  path = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str1) + 1 + strlen(str2) + 1));
  path = strcpy(path, str1);
  path = strcat(path, "/");
  path = strcat(path, str2);
  return (path);
}
```

Anyone knows something about it?

Comment: `C:/../test/file.txt` is an invalid absolute path! There is no parent directory (`..`) of the root directory (`C:/`).

Comment: ".." was for the example. My path is not exaclty this one.

Comment: Also, I tried "/" and "\\" and "\", the error is the same.

Comment: You mention error, is there any error?

Comment: The function fail, so i go i my if and get the "add file to archive failed !!"

Comment: Provide a proper example of your path please. Before adding the file to the zip, do an `access` or `stat` to verify the file can be found with the path.

Comment: D:\dir1\dir2\file
And I fopen the file before calling the zip function to read the data inside, so the path is good

Comment: I don't see you __close__ the file. Maybe the zip function can't open the file because it is still open? You get the `result`, why don't you print it and lookup the error code?

Comment: I also see you treat your data as a string. But if it is binary data it can contain null characters.

Comment: And you should show us your _exact_ code. The snippets you show are inconsistent. For example the file name in the first snippet is `file_name` and in the second it is just `file`. What is it?

Comment: For my test, the file contains only readable characters. I close the file later in my function, before calling the zip function, I'll edit.

Comment: ...and you close the file __after__ the call to miniz. Of course you should close the file _before_ that.

Comment: I have tried both and the error also occurs. So it does not seem to be the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing helps, then you should lookup the sources. Following the code in [miniz on Github](https://github.com/richgel999/miniz), file `miniz_zip.c` line 4297 I see:

```
mz_bool mz_zip_add_mem_to_archive_file_in_place(...
```

which calls function `mz_zip_writer_validate_archive_name` to check the second filename provided that it cannot start with a drive letter (line 3069) and if so
returns FALSE with error set to `MZ_ZIP_INVALID_FILENAME`.

As to why this second filename may not be an absolute path, I don't know. If it is important to you, you could get the code from Github and adapt it.

Comment: In an code example provides by miniz, it's the archive file name then the file you want to add. Also, I already said my code is working with relative path (like ../file_to_archive) so this is not the matter.

I'm not used to post on stackoverflow, indeed this is my first post. So I already check my error and try to understand why this is not working by myself ;)
Stop judging like this, it will not help at all

Comment: What do you mean "is working"? Did you check the archive file and check what is in it? Do you have a link to where I can find that miniz example?

Comment: Anyway, the 2nd filename provided to `mz_zip_add_mem_to_archive_file_in_place` may not contain a drive letter or (back)slash. The code checks that. As to why, I don't know.

Comment: @GemsKnight, I adapted my answer. Indeed, I was a bit negative, my apologies. However, I did research on your problem you could have done yourself, in paticular check the error codes.

Comment: Here is the example : https://github.com/richgel999/miniz/blob/master/examples/example2.c
He zip 50 files and one directory, then check his archive.

And yes, my zip file is created and I can unzip it, and read the content of the files in it. (with the relative path)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll modify the miniz source code.